# scrollTop() doesn't work with TextArea on IE

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

This question is quite common however I haven't seen a quite similar problem to mine. I have my .cshtml file where I've declared a TextArea using the Microsoft MVC HtmlHelpcer class. The code is the following:

```
@Html.TextArea("contentContainer", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "style", "width: 100%; height: 600px" } })
```

Then I have a function which is reading from a LogFile all the time and appending/adding the content of this file to this TextArea everytime there is an update. So I have my function in jQuery which appends the content to the TextArea and then I want it to Scroll the TextArea to the very bottom of the TextArea. The code is quite simple:

```
appendContent: function (content) {

    var $textArea = $('#contentContainer');
    var shouldBeScrolled = true;

    $textArea.append(content);

    var shouldBeScrolled = true;
    if (shouldBeScrolled) {
        $textArea.scrollTop(
           $textArea[0].scrollHeight
        );
    }
}
```

Please ignore the shouldBeScrolled variable. I just have it cause later I plan to create some constraints on scrolling.

OK, basically this code works perfect on Chromium, the content gets appended and the TextArea is scrolled to the bottom. **On Internet Explorer it simply doesn't scroll.** Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could very well be a bug in JQuery - I had the same issue before, and as a workaround I ended up scrolling to another item that contains my TextArea and has its top boundary coincident with the TextArea.

Something like this:

```
<div id="TextAreaContainer">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

And then the Javascript would look like:

```
$("#TextAreaContainer").scrollTop();
```

Comment: Why would you consider this a bug in jQuery if it works perfect on Chromium?

Comment: Because JQuery, like most JavaScript libraries, runs different code on different browsers in order to account for their differences.
EDIT: - tipically small portions of its code - just the "close to the metal" part that relies on the boxing model behaving the way it should.

Comment: Also, which version of IE and JQuery are you using?

Comment: Alright, so I will see if anyone else has an idea.. If not I will try your approach. So basically what you did was creating a div, which contains the TextArea inside right? You make them having the same "size" so you end up Scrolling this div? How do you exactly did this? Could you provide a little bit more detailed explanation? I'd appreciate :D

Comment: Something like this:

    `<div id="TextAreaContainer">
    <textarea></textarea>
    </div>`

And then the Javascript would simply be:

    `$("#TextAreaContainer").scrollTop();`

But again, if you find a better way to make it work on your textarea, good for you!

EDIT: code does not indent in comments, it seems.

Comment: Ciriaachi I will try your approach. If it will work correctly I will mark your answer as the good one. Maybe you will want to edit it eventually :) Thanks mate

Comment: The thing with your approach is that.. Now I scroll the div but the textarea inside is not getting scrolled, only the div. So I see now two scroll bars next to each other: One belonging to div and one belonging to text area :/

Comment: I need more context to help you.
Can you upload a code snippet that will help me to assess the situation?

Even better - can you upload it somewhere on the web?

Comment: I solved the question by removing the TextArea for real. So basically now I only have the div and I append the content directly to the div without the use of any text area. Thanks for your help :)